# Styles in Word 2010 - Return key isn't inserting new line

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to configure a document template, I've set up most styles but I've come to do `Title` and `Subtitle` but I'm encountering some strange behaviour.

I choose the `Title` style, write my title and hit return. The style of the text at the caret (i.e. the `style of following paragraph` setting) changes to `normal` (As I'd expect) but it doesn't insert a new line.

Is this a bug, or is there some setting somewhere controlling this behaviour that I can't find?

I have the same behaviour with `Subtitle`, but no other styles (that I've found)

Thanks

Comment: What is the behaviour of your default Word template for Title? If it behaves correctly, then compare the style settings. I took a quick look and there's nothing obvious that would cause such behaviour.

Comment: I think it was a bug. It's not doing it now :s